# How can I debug a each scenarios in my feature file separately

Tags: unit-testing, mstest, specflow

I have a test project that I wrote to test different services in the same solution. I used specflow and I have many scenarios to test. 
In order to debug my test I have to run my services. about 3 of them.
The problem I have now is If I go to the test explorer window and right click on a single scenario and try to debug, the option is disabled.
If I right click on the features file and select the option debug specflow scenarios it debug all my scenarios but I don't want that. 
how can I debug a each scenarios in my feature file separately while running my services?

Note: I am using msTest and VS2012.

Comment: Long term, I'd also recommend that you add some low level unit tests, (that don't rely on debugging like this) in addition to your integration tests. You want to avoid anything like inter-process communication, file system, and focus on testing the smallest possible units of your code. Make it easy to repeat your tests so you can attach the debugger easily. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Well you could switch to NUnit, the NUnitTestAdapter supports running individual tests.

You don't have to do it permanently, just long enough to debug this test.

Answer (score 0):

Or, add a Debugger.Launch() in the method that is bound to your When. Let all the other tests finish, and then step through this way. You will of course need to connect to the other services using Debug > Connect to process..., before stepping across the process boundary.